# How to completely disable the sound effect at all for an invalid action?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Here's the problem that I have

- My Bluetooth headset is connected to my smartphone and laptop.
- I'm listening to music using the smartphone.
- When I do some invalid action using the laptop my music gets interrupted.

I know how to volume down not to make a sound effect for an invalid action but what I want is to completely disable the sound effect so that my Bluetooth headset is not interrupted by it.

How can I completely disable the sound effect?

FYI, these threads don't have the answer

- [How do I disable the beep in OSX Leopard when I perform an invalid action?](https://superuser.com/questions/98868/how-do-i-disable-the-beep-in-osx-leopard-when-i-perform-an-invalid-action)
- [How can I get the Mac Terminal to not beep?](https://superuser.com/questions/163994/how-can-i-get-the-mac-terminal-to-not-beep)
- [Mac: disable the “boop” sound played when search results are not found](https://superuser.com/questions/278142/mac-disable-the-boop-sound-played-when-search-results-are-not-found)

**Update**

- I still want to listen to the sound of my laptop when it plays videos or something. I want to disable only the sound of an invalid input.
- Even if I set the alert volume to zero my music still get interrupted by the sound effect of an invalid action - the sound effect doesn't make any sound but my music stops for some seconds as my laptop plays a sound effect without a sound.

So I want to know the way to completely disable the sound effect of an invalid input, not the way of muting it.

Comment: I'd already added my answer before looking at the links... which I now see are exactly the same. Why does this method not work for you?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the answer. I want to listen to the sound of some videoes or something from my laptop that's why I have my headset connected to my laptop and smartphone at the same time. And that's why I want to disable only the sound effect of an invalid action. Also, I don't want to choose _Internal Speakers_ manually whenever I connect my headset.

Comment: That doesn't really seem to explain why the existing answers [or my identical answer] don't work.

Comment: I've added more explanation. Hope it clarified my question.

Comment: I have no idea why an alert sound either turned down or sent to a completely different output would interrupt your audio playback. I've been sending audio & alerts to separate outputs for a decade & never seen that issue.

Comment: Turning the volume down doesn't work for me as it still plays a sound without making a sound. Choosing _Internal Speakers_ works but like I said before I don't want to choose it manually whenever I use my headset that's why I'm looking for a way to disable the sound effect completely.

Comment: FWIW, I created a 1 millisecond sound file using an input source that had no input at the time of the recording and saved it in and as `~/Library/Sounds/No Sound.aiff`. Then in System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects, I selected No Sound under Select an alert sound:. Even with Alert volume: set to the high end of the slider it doesn't make a sound nor does it interrupt the other sound output that's currently playing. Note though that I do not have a Bluetooth Headset to test with, however other sound output sources were not interrupted by the alert sound when it was triggered. YMMV

Comment: BTW I used [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) to create the sound file. Note that I have no affiliation with the developers of Audacity and simply use the app because it's free.

Comment: @user3439894 That sounds like a cool hack. Unfortunately, I don't have my headset to test with at the moment. I'm going to try your hack soon and let you know.

Comment: BTW If what I presented works of you, you can use AppleScript to toggle the sound selection between No Sound and your default sound programmatically so you don't have to do it manually when wanting to use No Sound over the default alert sound. Let me know if this works and I can post it as an answer along with the example AppleScript code and how to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tested, the 1 millisecond sound file still interrupt my music. Speaking of AppleScript, do you think it would be possible to choose Internal Speakers for sound effects when my laptop connect to Bluetooth. That could be an workaround if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can set alerts to a different output, i.e. Internal Speakers, and/or turn the Alert volume: down completely.

System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects

[image: Sound Effects Tab]